# Checksum Bad error on boot

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, cmos

Recently I inserted a new 2GB ram in my motherboard, and got Checksum Bad error on bootup.
Upon reading other forums I assumed my CMOS battery must have been dead. 
I replace this with a new one and set the date/time in BIOS and yet I get Checksum Bad error. Now I'm stuck and need someone's assistance. It gets frustrating I have to set BIOS everytime I boot my machine. Is it because of the new RAM I just inserted?


My two RAMs are as follows: **2GB DDR2 6400 (400 MHz)** and **2GB DDR2 5300 (333 MHz)**.

Comment: What RAM did you recently install, the 6400 or 5300? Does it start normally if you go back to old RAM set up?

Comment: It's the 5300. It still does not start normally if I take it out.